# Declaring the name of argument when invoking a function

Tags: function, arguments, julia, keyword-argument

In `Julia 1.4.0` I have the following function:

```
function output(W::Int64,F::Int64,P::Int64,S::Int64)
       return ((W-F+2*P)/S +1)
       end
```

When I enter the following command, the output is as expected

```
julia> output(28,5,0,1)
24.0
```

Now, in order to be sure which argument is what, I what to explicitly name them when invoking the function (which could be helpful if one could write the argument in a different order if it is possible)

```
julia> output(W=28,F=5,P=0,S=1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching output(; W=28, F=5, P=0, S=1)
Closest candidates are:
  output(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at REPL[23]:2 got unsupported keyword arguments "W", "F", "P", "S"
  output(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at REPL[2]:2 got unsupported keyword arguments "W", "F", "P", "S"
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[25]:1
```

Is an other similar approach possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use keyword arguments for your function (you can read more about keyword arguments [in the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Keyword-Arguments-1))

To declare your function with keyword arguments you should do this (note the semi-colon before the arguments):

```
function output(;W::Int64,F::Int64,P::Int64,S::Int64)
       return ((W-F+2*P)/S +1)
end
```

Then, you can run your function as you wanted:

```
julia> output(W=28,F=5,P=0,S=1)
24.0
```

Comment: Many thanks @ARamirez. Indeed it works. Do you know what is the advantage of declaring a function with the semi-colon. Why just not having one way of declaring the function (without that semi-colon)?

Comment: This is a good question - the thing about `;` is that it separates positional from keyword arguments, and only positional arguments participate in method dispatch (see e.g. the discussion here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/rules-for-method-dispatch-with-keyword-arguments/23626/3). 

To illustrate consider the difference between `f(x::Number) = "a number!"; f(x::Int) = "an integer!"` and `g(;x::Number) = "a number"; g(;x::Int) = "an integer"`. You'll find that for `g`, only one method exists as the 2nd method overwrote the 1st, while for `f` there's a method for `Int` and one for `Float`